# How do I make my program continue on?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that will draw a "cootie" monster. The player inputs a number, either a 1 or 2 for now, and the program draws the monster for them. (A 1 gives you the body and a 2 gives you the head BUT, before you can draw the head, you HAVE to draw the body first)

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to get my program to keep going until the user has drawn both the head and the body. Right now, my program only gets 1 user input before ending, even though the player hasn't drawn the whole monster yet. Help is appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cootie {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("BODY PARTS:");
        System.out.println("1 = body");
        System.out.println("2 = head");
        System.out.println("3 = one leg");
        System.out.println("4 = one antenna");
        System.out.println("5 = one eye");
        System.out.println("6 = tail");
        System.out.println("What number did you roll?: ");

        int rollValue = scanner.nextInt();
        int body = 0;
        int error = 0;
        int head = 0;

        if (rollValue == 1) {
            if (body == 0) {
                body = 1;
            } else {
                error = 1;
            }
        } else if (rollValue == 2) {
            if (body == 1 && head == 0) {
                head = 1;
            } else {
                error = 1;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Enter a valid input!");
        }

        if (body == 1) {
            System.out.println("You got the body!");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("   [ ]");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("   [ ]");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("   [ ]");
        } else if (head == 1) {
            System.out.println("You got the head!");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("  (    )");
        }

        if (error == 1) {
            System.out.println("Can't add body part!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to learn about either loops or recursion.

Comment: make use of some `loop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some pseudocode. You need to continually execute the code in your main until youve received enough to draw your Cootie monster. The scanner only asks for one input unless wrapped in a loop

```
boolean done = false
while(!done){
    All of the code in your main
    if(condition that means cootie monster is finished)
       done = true;
}
```

Comment: I think the op wants this has drawn both the head and the body. when both and body have been drawn the loop is over

Comment: Yes, when both the head and body are drawn, then the program finishes. :)

Comment: so then `condition that means cootie monster is finished` = head and body are drawn.

Comment: Thanks! Gotcha, makes sense to me. :)

Comment: Think of done as your loop breaking condition. At the end of each loop, you evaluate the set of rules that mean a Cootie monster is drawn. If all these rules are true, you set done to true. The while loop then evaluates !done, which evaluates to not true, and does not execute the body

Answer (score 0):

This is a example to give you some ideas what to do

**Code**:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    do {
        System.out.println("what is going on?");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        list.add(input.next());
     } while(!(list.contains("hi") && list.contains("bye")));

    System.out.println("you said hi and bye");
```

**output**:

[image]

**Explantion**: In the code, as long as you have not entered hi and bye , the loop keeps looping

Comment: I think something's wrong with my code for head, because when I input a 2 after I draw the body, it says it can't add the body part. :( So I'm trying to figure that out right now.

Comment: I found the problem spot, but I don't know whit's happening. :( "Body" is being set back to 0 before it enters "if (rollValue == 2)...", so the head is never getting drawn. :P

Comment: No, your answer helped, I think the other one's just easier for me to understand. :)